# Can I post to another org's Chatter Feed using HTTP POST?

Tags: rest-api, chatter

I'm trying to do this, but using HTTP POST to another org...is this possible?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_define_post_action_link_template.htm

I haven't been able to make it work following those instructions.

Answer (score 0):

1.The first step should be provide an ability for your app to do an oauth dance with the other SFDC system .Once an oauth dance is completed ,store the oauth token in protected custom setting.

2.Call the REST API [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_define_post_action_link_template.htm) .

Its important you create action in the target instance and use the endpoint generated to call from your source org